# How to write in a txt-file, iOS 7

Tags: ios, file, text

I'm trying to make an iPhone app, for iOS 7.
I've created a txt file in my project, and want to be able to write the text from the txt file, when I push the write-button, write, and be able to read data, when I push the read-button, read.

I'v found this method working, when I try to read data:

```
- (IBAction)load:(id)sender {
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"text" ofType:@"txt"];
if (filePath) {
    NSString *stringFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [TextView setText:stringFromFile];
}
```

}

On another button, I want it to write data to the txt file in my project.
I've tried a lot of methods, but no of really works - it simple won't write text in the file. 
I've found one method, which works 50%. That means that it's not able to save the text I'm telling it to write, it only shows that it put's the text in the text box.

code:

```
- (IBAction)write:(id)sender {

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
                                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text"];


    //NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"text" ofType:@"txt"];

    NSString *printString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The new text"];

    [printString writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    if (filePath) {
        NSString *stringFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        [TextView setText:stringFromFile];
    }
}
```

Can any one please help me out?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Why are you trying to write to a text file?

Comment: Catch the error in writeToFile: instead of passing nil!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function :

```
-(void) writeToTextFile
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
        (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.txt", 
                                                  documentsDirectory];
    NSString *content = @"Your Desired Content";
    [content writeToFile:fileName 
                     atomically:NO 
                           encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy 
                                  error:nil];

}
```

Comment: Do not build the path using `stringWithFormat:`. Use `stringByAppendingPathComponent` like the OP does in the question.

Comment: and catch the error... There is a reason most such calls do allow passing NSError objects.